# Android: AsyncThread forces me to close my app

Tags: android, multithreading

I am relatively new to Android. I am trying to use AsyncTask but after the thread is being executed, my app is forces me to close it. Inside my Async thread I executing php on the server side which saves data from Android sensors. Any help will be highly  appreciated. Thanks

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
 .....
 final FuncionsActivity functions = new FuncionsActivity();
 if(something)
    functions.execute(nameValuePairs); 
 .....
  }

 private class FuncionsActivity extends 
       AsyncTask<ArrayList<NameValuePair>, Integer, Integer > {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... data) {
         // 1) Connect via HTTP. 2) Encode data. 3) Send data.
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new     

                  HttpPost("http://.../saveCoordinates.php");                           
            //HttpPost httppost = new 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data[0]));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
            this.onPostExecute(null);
                //Could do something better with response.
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error1:  " + e.toString());
        }
      return 0;     
      }

      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... item){
            Log.d("TestP", item[0] + " item has been processed");
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
            Log.d("TestP", "AsyncTask returned : " + result);
      }
 }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {            
    super.onDestroy(); // Move to bottom
    //System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
}
}
```

Comment: ugh, don't call a subclass of AsynchTask an "Activity", with Activity in Android you usually refer to something completly different.

Comment: haha, I feel like S.O should automatically have an input section for errors so users with 10 votes or less can't post until they add that. So we can't blame new users for not posting error logs. But it'd be helpful to know what Android is telling you that went wrong :)

Comment: Hm it's also strange that you access the ArrayList with array syntax. As far I know, that is not possible and should make a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call `onPostExecute()` yourself, the system will do it with whatever you return in `doInBackground()`.

I guess changing the line to `return null` like the other answer says, could fix the issue, but it's probably not what you want. You probably want to return an integer, extracted from the response, or something else.

Another strange thing in your code is `data[0]`, data is an ArrayList, does that compile? You also can't be defining a new variable data since this would produce duplicate variable compiler error.

Comment: Thank you all. I tried it works only one time. When I am trying to execute the thread again it still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
this.onPostExecute(null);
```

to this:

```
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying to call post Execute Method inside Background Method. It's called automatically. Remove it and try it

Hope it helps

Comment: I execute the thread inside onSensorChanged() and it gives me an error saying that it's out of memory. Within few seconds I get threadid = 500. Is this acceptable?